# Optimizing execution time for mapping array to value with dictionary and numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to implement a simple mapping to a set of values from an array created with numpy of 2-D.

For each row in the array I need to choose the correct value corresponding with the set of values and add it to a array.

For example:

[0, 1, 0, 0] -> 3
...
[1, 0, 1, 0] -> 2

But, my first implementation made me wonder if I'm doing something really wrong or not efficient at all because of the size of my dataset, so I did this workaround without using for loops and optimize speed execution using dictionary lookup.

```
import numpy as np

# function to perform the search and return the index accordingly (it is supposed to be fast because of data structure)
def get_val(n):
    map_list = {0: [0, 1, 0], 1: [0, 1, 0], 2: [1, 0, 0], 3: [0, 0, 1]}

    map_vals = list(map_list.values())
    index = map_vals.index(list(n))

    return(index)

# set of arbitrary arrays
li = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

# here is the performance improvement attempt with the help of the function above
arr = [get_val(n) for n in li]

print(arr)
```

I'm not completely sure if this is the correct way to do it for getting the needed value for a set like this. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Otherwise, I refer to my main question:

- what is the best way possible to optimize the code?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Create map_vals only once, not repeatly

Comment: Okay, that's a great point. But after this trivial correction, what is the way possible to optimize the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use matrix multiplication (dot product):

```
a=np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) # dict values 
c=np.array([0,1,2,3]) #  dict keys
li = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
b=np.linalg.pinv(a)@c # decoding table
result=li@b
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex Alex. But, would you mind trying to explain why this code is more efficient than my last approach? And more details on the decoding part. Sorry for the inconvenience, I am still trying to learn python.

Comment: Мy code is efficient because the matrix multiplication is efficiently done in numpy. SIMD instructions are used.